# I am trying to change this React class component into a Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The reason why I want to is, I am used to functional components, and the rest of my code is written with functional components so I'd like to keep it that way. I have actually never learned class components (I am still very new with coding), we just went in with Functional components, perhaps because of the React Hooks, and although I have read things online, I am having a hard time trying to convert this. This is the code I am trying to convert:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
 
class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
  }
 
  onChange = date => this.setState({ date })
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Calendar;
```

I've only managed to convert some of it to a functional component like this:

```js
import React {useState} from "react";

import Calendar from "react-calendar";

export default function Calendar () {
    const[date, setDate] = useState({date: new Date()})
```

I am even unsure if what I started is correct, but this is all I have so far with converting. I don't know how to convert the rest.

Comment: You're on the right track, keep going! [The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) has all the info you need. But don't use an object wrapper around the date, just `useState(new Date())` and later in the change callback, `setDate(date)`.

Comment: For the `onChange`, you just define the function in the body of the functional component, though might want to use `useCallback` to wrap it, so that it's memoized. See docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback . For the rendering, that's just simply what you return in the function, so that doesn't really change at all. You're pretty much there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';

export default () => {
  const[date, setDate] = useState({date: new Date()});
  return (
    <div>
      <Calendar
        onChange={date => setDate({ date })}
        value={date}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';

 const Calendar = () => {
 const[date, setDate] = useState({new Date()});

  onChange = date => setDate(date);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={date}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Calendar;
```